# Looking for historical data on NBA player-specific salaries and other contract information

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, sports, historical

I would like to find data that describe every player contract in the NBA, as far back into the past as possible. Optimally, this would include salary, term of contract, player agency, etc.

I search extensively and could not find. It seems that USATODAY had a similar database, but now they only have it for MLB, as in [this](http://www.usatoday.com/sports/mlb/salaries/) link.

Can someone propose a source where I can find these data for an NBA, as detailed as possible and ranging over as many years as possible? Thank you kindly.

Comment: Not historic but maybe it helps you/others with similar questions: On this site (http://www.basketball-reference.com/contracts/) you can find the actual salaries for this season (16/17), as well as for the next 4-5 years for all NBA players. You might have to scrape the data from the website, though.

Comment: Thanks. Scraping is not an issue. However, I do need historical data..

Answer (score 1):

Individual player pages on basketball-reference include *some* historical information, e.g. http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html

Patricia Bender's [pages](https://www.eskimo.com/~pbender/index.html) have half decent historical information but will be messy to handle.